# What if your repository history infringes a license?

Tags: licensing

I came across [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5990/handling-copyright-infringement-in-your-own-open-source-project) which answers what should be done if you find that your open source project infringes a license.

One of the answers states it's ok to simply remove the infringing code. However, the repository history will always have the infringing code and anyone will have access. Is it really enough to simply remove the code and from now on live a non-gangster-criminal-code-thief-thug life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might not be enough. You might need to edit the history of the repo you publish and remove the infringing code so that all (public) history is on compliance with copyright and licenses.

The actual answer of what actions are necessary and which are nice but not required likely depends on the exact circumstances. IANAL